# Creating a knowledge base with SP10 possible?

Tags: development, wiki

I am currently trying to create some kind of knowledge base, but unfortunately couldn't make much progress in this matter.

I have certain requirements of features the system must provide in the end and hope that you guys can help me realizing them with SP10.

The main requirement would be usability. What I definitely need is some kind of template which is used whenever creating new pages/entries in the knowledge base. This template should include certain webparts (e.g. a Document library) that always need to be in the same position.

Next thing would be some kind of tagging functionality whenever uploading a document through the document library (preferably in the pop-up GUI that comes up when clicking "upload new document"). Those tags should also be available to the SP search engine so that users searching for tags get all the documents tagged with that term as results.

Another requirement would be the availability of linking features between the knowledge base articles like in a Wiki or something.

Is such a thing possible with Sharepoint? What would be the best practice to implement it? Wiki Page libraries and the enterprise wiki don't look too bad, but I'm not sure how to set them up correctly so that they fit my requirements. Hope some of you can help or give me some directions.

best regards,
daZza

Answer (score 1):

That's easily doable and if you look on codeplex, you can see a complete implementation that was made during a 3 days conference by SharePoint MVP / Experts : http://spkbase.codeplex.com/

Starting with this, you'll have all the foundations (& more) for your solution and you just need to configure / customize to further business needs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds awesome, will have a read through it in the next days and try to implement it. Thanks

Comment: I tried to implement this solution, but it doesn't seem to work... For whatever reason the developers didn't provide a finished .wsp SP Solution but only some folder structure in a .zip file.

I tried to build the solution myself using Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, but I couldn't open the .sln / .csproj files in any of them. Always got an error message telling me that this type of file cannot be opened -.-

Comment: You need to take the separate parts on the right "other downloads" from here http://spkbase.codeplex.com/releases/view/86510 depending on your needs. Start with http://spkbase.codeplex.com/releases/view/86512 which is the foundation and then add relevant functionnalities based on your environment (premise, cloud) & license.

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought it would be best to take the newest, all-in-one version. Will give it another try tomorrow.

edit: just checked out the file you linked and it's the same with that again... And the instructions.txt seems to be trolling me as well, lol:

INSTRUCTIONS
=============
Welcome to the awesome SharePoint 2010 Project template provided by International SharePoint Conference 2012!


TODO: Enter instructions here

Comment: I just grab it locally and extract the package, I guess you pick the wrong one. Mine is extracted properly and has all the content inside. HIH

Comment: I picked all of them and it's the same for each. I would expect a .wsp file so I can deploy the solution/module to my Sharepoint Site Collection. Right now all I have is hundreds of files in different folders and no clue what to do with them :(

Comment: You need to package them through Visual Studio. The idea is that you have all the source to adapt & configure it to your need rather that a stand alone wsp without access to the code.
Grab a trial edition of VS2010 / 2012 if you don't have one and one the .sln file then right click on the project and pick "package".

Comment: I did that (see above). I tried with VS 2010 and 2012, but both versions said that the provided sln files are incompatible :(

Comment: Did you install the SharePoint SDK? that installs the project templates so you can work on it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thats quite a heap of questions in one! 
In my opinion what you're asking about IS SharePoint, and as such there are hundreds of answers to your solution, all of which could be correct. 
We have been developing a knowledge base/training portal (they have been merged) for a short while now. With your main requirement being usability I would be sure to focus on the search and tagging aspect. This requires a well thought out taxonomy structure, for which I would recommend getting together with a focus group of users to create. Once this is in place its really down to personal preference. 
We have done it through a series of sites with document libraries. This gives us the ability to filter the documents by program, subject, rating etc etc. It also means that if a user just wants to learn something about Excel but arent sure what (a bit of personal development) they can just head on over to the excel library and browse the topics until they see something of use.

Like I said, there's not really one right answer - this is just the approach we're taking after testing a few methods. By all means drop me a line if you want to ask about what we're doing - though I am certainly no SharePoint expert!